# Bootstrap margin-bottom not working on small device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I am having problem with nested rows where margin bottom does not seem to work on one of the sections. I am attaching a picture. There should be a gap between first and second div. It is working fine on big screen, it seem to break on small devices.

Here is the code:
CSS:

```
.row > div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="section">First div</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                <div class="section">Second div</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="section">Third div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code on smaller resolution and it looks the same. Please specify better what is unusual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This selector will solve your problem. You were just calling the first div inside your row when the actual problem was the separation between the columns inside.

```
.row > div > div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

This will mantain all the bottom margins of that row at 15px.

If you want to stick with your previous solution you can do it in other way, this will make it that the margin bottom (15px+15px) is the same as the separation between columns (15px+15px) in bigger screens and a normal 15px on small screens.

```
.row > div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.row > div > div:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you used the wrong selector. If you use:

```
.row div{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

The gap between first and second div will appear. This selector matches with all descendants divs.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class onphonemargin in your first div like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 onphonemargin">
                <div class="section">First div</div>
            </div>
```

And add this css

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){

.onphonemargin{margin-bottom:15px;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.row > div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

.row > div > div:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.row > div > div:nth-child(2)
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/vkke8u9b/)